# Document Library folder permissions

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions

This is driving me crazy...
When I send an Email to a document library, obviously the Folder(s) name is created based on the Email Subject, and it's attachment is then uploaded to said folder.
Now when it is created, it Adds/Inherits Permissions (from where, I don't know)...
The Folder's Parent is obviously the Document Library itself (right?).
The Document Library has hundreds of users

When the Folder is created by the Email... it Inherits only a few Users...
Questions: Where is this list of users being pulled from if not the Parent?

Thanks.